# docopt required options and options with arguments

Tags: python, arguments, docopt

I am new to docopt and am having a bit of difficulty getting a small example working. I'm having two small problems just now and would welcome assistance on those problems and more general comments on improving the code. The first problem is getting the program to require the `--required` option. It should print the docstring on running without the required command line option. The second problem is getting the program to accept arguments (such as `COMPUTER`) for options (such as `--computer`). How would this be specified in the terminal and how should it be coded?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
my example program

Usage:
    docopt_example_1.py [--ipaddress=IPADDRESS] [--computer=COMPUTER]
    docopt_example_1.py --network <network>
    docopt_example_1.py (--required)
    docopt_example_1.py --notrequired
    docopt_example_1.py --version

Arguments:
    IPADDRESS               I.P. address
    COMPUTER                computer identification
    <network>               network identification

Options:
    -h, --help              Show this help message.
    --version               Show the version and exit.
    --required              option required for running
    --notrequired           option not required for running
    --ipaddress=IPADDRESS   I.P. address
    --computer=COMPUTER     computer identification
    --network=NETWORK       network identification
"""
from docopt import docopt

def main(options):
    print("----------")
    print("a printout of the command line options as parsed by docopt:")
    print(options)
    print("----------")
    if options["--notrequired"]:
        print("required option selected")
    if options["--computer"]:
        print("computer name: {computer}".format(computer=options["COMPUTER"]))
    if options["--network"]:
        print("computer name: {network}".format(network=options["<network>"]))
    else:
        print("no options")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = docopt(__doc__, version='1')
    main(options)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your 1st problem, "All elements are required by default, if not included in brackets". All usage lines are parallel, which means inputs only need to match any one of usage lines, it will be considered valid. So you need to add 'required parameters' into all usage lines:

```
Usage:
    docopt_example_1.py --required [--notrequired] [--ipaddress=IPADDRESS] [--computer=COMPUTER]
    docopt_example_1.py --required [--notrequired] --network <network>
    docopt_example_1.py --version
```

In the above example, if your input is not "docopt_example_1.py --version" and doesn't contain "--required", it will print the docstring on running.

---

Regarding 2nd problem, read the arguments of options by using the option names:

```
print("computer name: {computer}".format(computer=options["--computer"]))
print("network name: {network}".format(network=options["--network"]))
```

---

Besides, you may want to take care of the note from official site:

> writing --input ARG (opposed to --input=ARG) is ambiguous, meaning it
>   is not possible to tell whether ARG is option's argument or positional
>   argument. In usage patterns this will be interpreted as option with
>   argument only if option's description (covered below) for that option
>   is provided. Otherwise it will be interpreted as separate option and
>   positional argument.

The help understand it, if you remove this line

```
--network=NETWORK       network identification
```

and inputs are `docopt_example_1.py --required [--notrequired] --network network_name`, then you won't be able to read "network_name" from `options['--network']`, instead you need to use `options['<network>']`. Because in this case "network_name" is considered a separate positional argument.

---

Btw, the following lines seem have logic bug. The `else` only bond to the last `if`. I think this's not what you expected:

```
if options["--notrequired"]:
    print("required option selected")
if options["--computer"]:
    print("computer name: {computer}".format(computer=options["COMPUTER"]))
if options["--network"]:
    print("computer name: {network}".format(network=options["<network>"]))
else:
    print("no options")
```

Reference: http://docopt.org/

Comment: Ah, excellent. Thank you very much for your help. I hadn't quite seen that the usage lines are considered in parallel. Thank you very much for your other recommendations.